Calculating cumulative sum with date filtering in a table
I have a table with two columns (DateTime and Result) and I need a cumulative sum of the results, starting from 0 for each day.



DataTime
Result




2023-12-20 09:02:00
-10


2023-12-20 11:02:00
20


2023-12-20 12:04:00
45


2023-12-22 08:05:00
50


2023-12-22 09:14:00
32


2023-12-22 11:55:00
-10



The expected result is



DataTime
Result
Daily Result




2023-12-20 09:02:00
-10
-10


2023-12-20 11:02:00
20
10


2023-12-20 12:04:00
45
55


2023-12-22 08:05:00
50
50


2023-12-22 09:14:00
32
82


2023-12-22 11:55:00
-10
72



The expression
Daily Result = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Original'Result);
    FILTER(
        ALL('Original');
        Original[DateTime] <= EARLIER(Original[DateTime])
    )
)

returns the daily sum added to the previous day daily sum, like this:



DataTime
Result
Daily Result




2023-12-20 09:02:00
-10
55


2023-12-20 11:02:00
20
55


2023-12-20 12:04:00
45
55


2023-12-22 08:05:00
50
127


2023-12-22 09:14:00
32
127


2023-12-22 11:55:00
-10
127




you can try to create to create a column
Column =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        INT ( 'Table'[DataTime] ) = INT ( EARLIER ( 'Table'[DataTime] ) )
            && 'Table'[DataTime] <= EARLIER ( 'Table'[DataTime] )
    ),
    'Table'[Result]
)



Tks for helping!
It worked.
